# How to organize /home/ such that users don't see each other's content?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, apache-httpd, group

Up to know, I used a sandbox server *for myself only*, and websites were in subdirectories of `/home/www/`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Nov 30 14:45 www
|--- drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 14 22:04 mywordpress  (subdir of /home/www/)
```

The only users/groups I saw were `root` and `www-data`.

Now I'd like to allow a friend to host a website on this sandbox server. I created a user account `abcd`, and his home is `/home/abcd/`. In `/home/`, I currently have:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 abcd abcd 4096 Dec 10 12:02 abcd
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Nov 30 14:45 www
```

**Problem: if I log-in via SSH with the account `abcd`, I can still browse `/home/www/`, which I don't want!** Then I thougt I should just give `drwxr-xr--` permission to this directory, but then I fear that Apache/PHP-related things, often using `www-data`, won't be able to browse `/home/www/` anymore!

Question: can you recommend a simple directory structure of `/home/` of this sandbox server, allowing myself and a friend `abcd` to host Apache+PHP websites, without `abcd` being able to see my files in `/home/www/`? (NB: `www-data` should still be able to see the files, I think this is necessary?)

Comment: I already know https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes#Viewing_permissions but I don't know how to do it in a clever way here.

Comment: @Downvoter: can you leave a note about how to improve this question? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The question does not have a strait forward answer because there are additional details to address. However, the permissions portion is quite simple.

```
chgrp www-data /home/www
chmod 0750 /home/www
```

This maintains rwx for root, provides r-x for www-data, and removes all access for all others. This is not a recursive change, so the Word Press websites still have the write access that they need.

One might also give the user, `abcd`, a little privacy from any future users that are created in the same way.

```
chgrp www-data /home/abcd
chmod 0750 /home/abcd
```

Note that any user with access to the Web server might also be able to use it to read files in `/home/www`. For example, via a file inclusion of any kind... using the Web server itself or via a programming technology that the Web server uses, such as PHP. Further restriction may be required in the Web server configuration and in any Web programming language that has been installed, even CGI. **Remember that the `abcd` user has access to the `www-data` user; thus, this portion of the overall goal is a beginning, but not an end.**

---

To get a good answer on the remaining portion, please ask a new question with all of the details about the Web hosting environment.

- Operating system name and version
- Web server name and version
- Name and version of any Fast CGI software
- Fast CGI configuration
- The Apache configuration file
- The PHP version and configuration file(s)
- Other relevant information

Providing as much pertinent information as possible (without providing too much detail) will help the one who answers provide a detailed response. Perhaps subtract comments from posted files to eliminate as much "noise" as possible.